# I have a CSS overflow issue

Tags: html, css, overflow

On this website http://rwl.rwlwater.com/ I have a small issue... I added overflow: hidden to the featured slider div, the pictures were showing up stacked if the javascript was enabled or the user had a slow internet connection..

But now I have another problem.. The description had a little thing positioned outside the slider and it's hidden now...If I add overflow-x: visible it adds the scroll bar and that's not what I want. I want the description to be fully visible, but the overflow-y to be hidden.

Comment: Can you provide an example that is broken? I looked at the site and I don't see any scroll bars or other things that don't appear that they should be there.

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Check out http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html for examples of all combinations

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work, the scrollbar shows up. I need it to be fully visible without the scroll bar

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do then. If you use `overflow-x: auto` you can't set a height in case that's what you're seeing.

Comment: try removing the overflow-x and overflow-y to see how the description box looks like..that's how I want it to look even after I add the overflow to hide the other stacking images.

Answer (score 0):

In your `#slides .description` change

```
right: -11px;
```

to

```
right: 11px;
```

or something similar.

Works for me in Chrome inspect element.

Comment: It works but I need it to be outside of the featured slider div and not inside it.